# Prove if $T(\overline{S_1})$ is a bounded subset of $Y$ then $T$ is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed space, $T$ is linear operator on $X$ into $Y$, and
$$S_1=\{ x\in X : \| x \| \leq 1 \}.$$
Prove if $T(\overline{S_1})$ is a bounded subset of $Y$ then $T$ is bounded. ($\overline{S_1}$ denote closure of $S_1$).

I know the definition of bounded linear operator, i.e.

Let $X \text{ and } Y$ be normed vector spaces (both over $\mathbb R$ or over $\mathbb C$).
A linear transformation or linear operator $T : X \to Y $ is bounded if there is
a constant $C$ such that
$$\Vert Tx \Vert_Y \leq C\Vert x\Vert_X \text{ for all } x \in X.$$

Now, I don't know how to start the proof. I can't determine the closure of $S_1$. Any hint to prove it?

Comment: You know that $\overline{S_1}=S_1$, right?!

Comment: Thanks @Jose Carlos Santos.

Comment: Now, given $\Vert T({S_1})\Vert \leq C\Vert x\Vert \leq C $. I don't know to get $\Vert T(x)\Vert \leq C\Vert x\Vert$. Any hint to get it?

Comment: For any non-zero vector $x$, consider the vector $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ which lies in $S_1$.